# Formatar cor da table CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Gostaria de que minha tabela estivesse com esse visual.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas ao adicionar o conteúdo nela ele fica com essa visual não estou conseguindo deixa-la como a table de cima.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
function listarProdutos(){
    var conteudo="<table border='1'>";
     conteudo+="<tr>";
    conteudo+="<div class='indice'><p>Indice</p></div>"
    conteudo+="<div class='nome'><p>Nome</p></div>"
     conteudo+="</tr>";
    //pos contator
    for(var pos=1;pos<indice.length;pos++){
        conteudo+="<tr>";
        conteudo+="<td>"+indice[pos]+"</td>";
        conteudo+="<td>"+nomes[pos]+"</td>";
        conteudo+="</tr>";
    }
    conteudo+="</table>";
    document.getElementById("txtrelatorio").innerHTML=conteudo;
}

.indice, .nome{

        font-size: 15pt;
        font-weight: 700px;
        background-color: #000066;
    }

    tr,td{
        font-size: 14pt;
        background-color: #000066;
        color: #CCCCCC;
    }
```

Comment: Você esta declarando tr e td com o mesmo visual, separe um css para tr e outro para td, afinal TR é linha e TD é coluna. Logo, você está dando o mesmo css para toda a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basta utilizar este código que sua tabela ficará com o cabeçalho diferente do corpo

```html
<html>
            <head>
                <title>TODO supply a title</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <style>
                        tr{
                            font-size: 14pt;
                            background-color: white;
                            color: white;
                        }
                        th{
                            font-size: 14pt;
                            background-color: green;
                            color: white;
                        }
                        td{
                            font-size: 14pt;
                            background-color: #000066;
                            color: #CCCCCC;
                        }
                </style>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div>
                    <table border ='2'>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Índice</th>
                            <th>Nome</th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>1</td>
                          <td>Paula</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>2</td>
                          <td>Luisa</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
table thead{
    background: #2980b9;
    color: #FFF;
}

table tbody{
    background: #3498db;
    color: #FFF;
}

table thead tr td{
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
}

table tbody tr td{
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <td>Indice</td>
                <td>Nome</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Conteudo Primeiro</td>
                <td>Conteudo Segundo</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>    
</body>
</html>
```

Assim?